# Java web search

Tags: java, search, web

I have this code for the google search:

```
    int num_risultati=15;
    String only="+filetype%3Ahtml+OR+filetype%3Ahtm+OR+filetype%3Axhtm+OR+filetype%3Axhtml"; 

    String google = "http://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&num="+num_risultati+"&q="+only;
    String search = "\"Java\" \"C\"";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; 

    Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset)).userAgent(userAgent).get().select("li.g>h3>a");

    for (Element link : links) {
        String title = link.text();
        String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
        url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

        //System.out.println(url);

        if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
            continue; // Ads/news/etc.
        }

        System.out.println("Title: " + title);
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);

        System.out.println();
    }
```

In addition to seeking only documents html, htm, xhtm, xhtml I would also include links to wikipedia, that is, links that start with "en.wikipedia.org".

How can I add this in the query?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
 String only="+filetype%3Ahtml+OR+filetype%3Ahtm+OR+filetype%3Axhtm+OR+filetype%3Axhtml+OR+as_lq=en.wikipedia.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter Google searches with a specific domain like en.wikipedia.org using:

site:en.wikipedia.org

Try that instead of "as_lq=en.wikipedia.org". Also, you might not need that last OR operator before the site filter.